# What is a good backup program for Windows

Tags: windows-7, backup

I use Windows 7 on a RAID-0 harddrive array, and for christmas got a 1 TB Toshiba External harddrive. While the Toshiba comes with it's own backup program, this program fails for no error message I can decipher.

So, what is a good backup program that is compatible with windows? I don't much trust Windows backup system as it often fails on it's own.

Comment: Do you want to backup whole partitions/disks or just certain files?

Comment: I want to backup the entire partition

Answer (score 2):

I'm a fan of [Cobian](http://www.educ.umu.se/~cobian/cobianbackup.htm), it's free, older versions are open source; it supports disk, CD/DVD and FTP; it can do Full/Incremental/Differential backups, and has the option to keep multiple timestamped copies of files. In my experience, it's the most reliable backup software on Windows.

If you're looking to do remote backup, an rsync based solution is the best; Deltacopy is good.

Answer (score 2):

I like [FreeFileSync](http://sourceforge.net/projects/freefilesync/) for its simplicity and lightweightness. It is very clear and understandable and doesnt bundle the backedup files in to one big file

Answer (score 1):

If you want full drive backup (and even if you don't), Windows Backup is brilliant and I do not understand why you are saying it fails... perhaps you have more serious issues with your machine that you need to look in to.

Comment: I think the OP was saying that the Toshiba backup program fails... I agree that the Windows Backup facility will suit many people's requirements. The problem is that many people don't even realise that it's there...

Comment: I'm with you on this one, there's nothing wrong with Windows Backup. Any issues experienced with it should be investigated. It's definitely good enough.

Comment: I tried windows backup first, when I say it fails, I mean it goes so far, then says that the backup failed due to an error and the backup is unuseable. It litterally fails and I don't know why.

Comment: Have you looked in the event log? Or can you try again and take a picture of the screen and I will see what I can do to help you.

Answer (score 1):

[CrashPlan](http://b8.crashplan.com/consumer/index.html) is excellent.  You can either back up online ($3.50 per month),  back up through a network to another computer, or back up to your external hard drive.

Answer (score 1):

**[Areca Backup](http://www.areca-backup.org/)** is excellent.

It basically allows you to select a set of files / directories to back-up, choose where and how (as a simple file copy, as a zip archive, ...) they will be stored, and configure post-backup actions (like sending backup reports by email or launching custom shell scripts)

It has been designed to :

- Be as simple as possible to set up : No complex configuration files to edit - Your backup configuration (which is stored as an XML file) can be edited with Areca's graphical user interface.
- Be as versatile as possible : Areca can use advanced backup modes (like "delta backup") or simply produce a "basic" copy of your source files as a standard directory or zip archive (readable by WinZip or other archivers).
- Allow you to interact with your archives and the files they contain : Track different versions of a specific file, browse your archives, recover or view specific files, merge a set of archives, ...

*Areca is free open source software.*

To Image and Backup logical Drives and Partitions, i recommend **[DriveImage XML](http://www.runtime.org/driveimage-xml.htm)**

*DIXML is freeware.*

Answer (score 0):

I really liked [syncback](http://www.2brightsparks.com/downloads.html#freeware). I used the freeware version. I liked the availability of synchronized folders, and syncback has a fairly easy to use gui.

Answer (score 0):

For basic file back-ups (not system back-ups), I use Microsoft’s [SyncToy](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15155) and schedule it to run, via the Windows Scheduler, at start-up.